# Vertical line/Separator

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a vertical line between these two items. But unable to figure out how to do so. Here are my two items.

```
  ${"City"}
  ${"Description"}
```

Comment: Add a `|` character??

Comment: yes.. something similar to City | Description

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `|` character. or:

You can create a `<hr></hr>` tags and then transform and rotate the line by `90deg`.

Sorry for not knowing the exact CSS transform.